# How to get a floating box when i click on a button in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to make this type of UI -

[image]

[image]

Like this dialog opens when we click on "Other Details" and appears just below it. Is there any package for this? Else I will try to use `stack` and `positioned`, and will position it as accurate as I can.

Comment: Native flutter: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ExpansionPanel-class.html or have you checked this package? https://pub.dev/packages/expandable

Answer (score 1):

You could use an [ExpansionTile](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ExpansionTile-class.html).
It does exactly what you are looking for.

Code sample:

```
Center(
    child: ExpansionTile(
      iconColor: Colors.red,
      title: const Text('More details'),
      children: [
        ListTile(
            title: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          children: const [
            Text('Name'),
            Text('Ankit'),
          ],
        )),
        ListTile(
            title: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          children: const [
            Text('Grade'),
            Text('9th'),
          ],
        )),
        ListTile(
            title: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          children: const [
            Text('Date of birth'),
            Text('21-04-2008'),
          ],
        )),
      ],
    ),
  )
```

[image: screenshot_closed]

[image: screenshot_opened]

Keep in mind that in the `children` you could put any widget, even a container, as:

[image: container]

---

### EDIT

After reading your clarifying comment this is what I made:
[image: infoBox]

Obviously it's a basic floating box, but you can customize it.

I used a [Stack](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Stack-class.html) to overlap widgets and a boolean to check if you need to show or not the infobox.

```
bool visibile = false;

Center(
        child: Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        IconButton(
            onPressed: () => setState(() {
                  visibile = !visibile;
                }),
            icon: const Icon(Icons.remove_red_eye)),
        Stack(
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          children: [
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: Column(
                children: const [
                  ElevatedButton(
                    onPressed: null,
                    child: Text("Check In"),
                  ),
                  TextField()
                ],
              ),
            ),
            visibile
                ? Container(
                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * .8,
                    height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * .5,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        boxShadow: [
                          BoxShadow(
                              offset: Offset.fromDirection(1, 2),
                              spreadRadius: 1,
                              blurRadius: 3,
                              color: Colors.grey)
                        ],
                        borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20)),
                        border: Border.all(
                            color: Colors.orange,
                            width: 2,
                            style: BorderStyle.solid)),
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                      child: SingleChildScrollView(
                        child: Column(
                          children: [
                            Row(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                              children: const [
                                Text(
                                  'Academic year',
                                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
                                ),
                                Text('2023'),
                              ],
                            ),
                            Row(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                              children: const [
                                Text(
                                  'Student name',
                                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
                                ),
                                Text('Ankit'),
                              ],
                            ),
                            Row(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                              children: const [
                                Text(
                                  'Grade',
                                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
                                ),
                                Text('9th'),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  )
                : Container(),
          ],
        ),
      ],
    ))
```

Having the button **outside** the Stack prevents the InfoBox to hide it and makes it so you can click it at any time.

---

I have no idea why, but someone with enough privileges keeps deleting my comments on this answer.

Comment: No, actually this widget expands on the screen itself. I want the panel to float, such that the content below more details hide. In this case, it will slide below as my panel will expand.

Answer (score 1):

If you Want the widget float on the other widgets, you can use OverlayEntry. There is a medium article/guide about this: [Click to read](https://medium.com/@gshubham030/custom-dropdown-menu-in-flutter-7d8d1e026c6b).

**Abstract:**

first you need a global key, an overlay widget and the other variables below:

```
  GlobalKey overlayKey = LabeledGlobalKey("button_icon");
  late OverlayEntry overlayEntry;
  late Size buttonSize;
  late Offset buttonPosition;
  bool isMenuOpen = false;
```

then add the global key to your button's key proprty:

```
key: context.read<MainViewModel>().overlayKey,
```

then, find the clicked button using this function:

```
  findButton() {
    RenderBox renderBox =
        overlayKey.currentContext!.findRenderObject() as RenderBox;
    buttonSize = renderBox.size;
    buttonPosition = renderBox.localToGlobal(Offset.zero);
  }
```

then, a builder:

```
  OverlayEntry overlayEntryBuilder() {
    return OverlayEntry(
      builder: (context) {
        return Positioned(
          top: buttonPosition.dy + buttonSize.height * 4 / 5,
          left: buttonPosition.dx - (buttonSize.width / 2) - 32,

          // width: buttonSize.width,
          child: YourWidgetThatWillOpenWhenYouClickTheButton(),
        );
      },
    );
  }
```

you can play around with the values in the Positioned widget to get the overlay where you want it.

now you can call these functions to open/close the overlay:

```
  void openMenu(BuildContext context) {
    findButton();
    overlayEntry = overlayEntryBuilder();
    Overlay.of(context)!.insert(overlayEntry);
    isMenuOpen = !isMenuOpen;
  }

  void closeMenu() {
    overlayEntry.remove();
    isMenuOpen = !isMenuOpen;
  }
```

like this:

```
IconButton(
        key: context.read<MainViewModel>().overlayKey,
        onPressed: () {
          if (!context.read<MainViewModel>().isMenuOpen) {
            context.read<MainViewModel>().openMenu(context);
          } else {
            context.read<MainViewModel>().closeMenu();
          }
        },
```

check the medium article for the detailed explanation.

Answer (score 1):

There is a way that works best for this types of scenario: When you wish a widget appears at a particular location but should overlap all widgets or some widgets around it.

The solution utilizes two widgets:

1. [CompositedTransformTarget](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/CompositedTransformTarget-class.html): the child of this widget acts sort of like a placeholder widget or as a part-of a group of UI but the main purpose is for this widget to be sitting at the desired location.
2. [CompositedTransformFollower](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/CompositedTransformFollower-class.html): No matter where this widget is located, the child of this widget is bound to follow or attach itself to the position of the **CompositedTransformTarget** widget. You can further adjust the offset property in the horizontal and vertical coordinate to give a shift from the origin position of the **CompositedTransformTarget**.

Why are these two widgets necessary? Because your aim is to accomplish an overlaying of the **CompositedTransformFollower**'s child over other widgets surrounding it while it is placed at the desired position of **CompositedTransformTarget**.

The common way to accomplish the overlay is to use the Flutter’s pre-provided Stack, the Overlay which overlay's the widgets you put in it over every other widgets on your screen with an OverlayEntry.

Here is a very [simple and good tutorial](https://medium.com/saugo360/https-medium-com-saugo360-flutter-using-overlay-to-display-floating-widgets-2e6d0e8decb9) on how to use the **OverlayEntry** with **CompositedTransformTarget** and **CompositedTransformFollower**.

However, the strength of the Overlay is also its drawback. Since it overlays everything on screen, it means that if you have an appBar and your screen scrolls, then your widget will also overlay the appBar and it does not respect SafeArea.

For most design that needs your overlay to respect the appBar and SafeArea and any other respectable thing then you have to come up with a better logic.

Since the Idea of overlaying is simply that: any widget that is built will have a higher z-index than widgets built before it and will thus overlay those previously built then you could use a Column or a Row, ListView, SingleChildScrollView or any other multichild widget in your design and just make sure that you include the **CompositedTransformFollower** as the last child of that parent widget. This way your desired widget will have a higher z-index than other children and as such when it gets attached to the **CompositedTransformTarget** sitting at your desired location then it will overlay other sibling widgets below it or above it in the parent widget.

A very exciting application of this logic is also to overcome the limitation of the unforgiving **Stack**. When you place a **Positioned** widget that goes outside the bounds of a Stack, then GestureDetector, InkWell and all touch event does not work.

To overcome this, You can place your Stack in a Column/Row, and then place **CompositedTransformFollower** in that same Column/Row. Make it target a Positioned **CompositedTransformTarget** placeholder widget inside the Stack and when it attaches itself to that Positioned placeholder it will not be affected by Stack; so touch events will work!!!!